# create Dotnetnuke module without database

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm starting with the development of modules in DotNetNuke 7 and want to develop a simple module, a module that reads an external XML and display it on a page.

My question is: For a module that does not need access to the database (as I want to develop), is it necessary to create a table in the database for the module? (steps 6, 7 and 8 in http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't be necessary, and you can remove any of the DataProvider/SqlDataProvider references.

Update: You'll want to remove the references in the .DNN file to any files you remove from your project as well.

Comment: And if you do not need the Edit view, does I can delete it?. For example, in a module which is a contact form, you only need store the destination email in settings, no need to edit anything.

Comment: Correct, you can remove the Edit.ascx file, its codebehind, and the RESX file in app_localresources.